# Design pattern to plot different methods of a single object

Tags: java, plot

I'm trying to figure out how to apply a Design Pattern to existing objects to plot different methods of the object.

I know how to "plot" in Java.  I have my objects already defined.  What I'd hate to do is:

```
myObject.plotMethodA(xMin, xMax)
myObject.plotMethodB(xMin, xMax)
```

I was hoping that there was a way to:

```
plotMethod(myObject.MethodA, xMin, xMax)
plotMethod(myObject.MethodB, xMin, xMax)
```

This mindset looks like passing a pointer to a function.  There's plenty of folks that advise against this in Java.  There must be a more elegant way to handle this, but I can't quite see how to map this to an existing design pattern.  Is the answer:

```
plotMethod(myObject, "Method A", xMin, xMax)
```

This is like issuing a "command" to the plotting object and handing them the object.  Then my plotting object works with the interface defined to operate with the class that represents the instance of myObject.  It has to spend a little time figuring out the string "command", but otherwise can select the appropriate method to plot.

Is there a better way?  Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what it means to "plot" something.  You should explain what that means.

Comment: Use the term plot as literal or abstract.  What I mean is that myObject has a series of methods.  These methods are simple functions:  e.g. myObject.MethodA(x) = x^2; myObject.MethodB(x) = x + 2.  I wish to graph this on the screen.  So, I am trying to understand a design pattern and Java implementation that will enable me to graph one of multiple methods that myObject has.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8 you can do this by passing in method references.  You can find how they work here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

*Conceptually*, you'll end up doing something similar to this:

```
plotMethod(myObject.MethodA, xMin, xMax)
plotMethod(myObject.MethodB, xMin, xMax)
```

But it will look like this, syntactically:

```
plotMethod(myObject::MethodA, xMin, xMax)
plotMethod(myObject::MethodB, xMin, xMax)
```

This is better than

```
plotMethod(myObject, "Method A", xMin, xMax)
```

because it will have some type safety.  For example, you'll only be able to pass in a method/function that takes and returns the correct parameters.

---

Here's some working code as an example:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

public class Sandbox {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassWithSimilarMethods obj = new ClassWithSimilarMethods();
        callMethod(obj::methodA, 1, 2);
        callMethod(obj::methodB, 1, 2);
    }

    private static void callMethod(BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> methodA, int x, int y) {
        methodA.accept(x, y);
    }


    public static class ClassWithSimilarMethods {

        public void methodA(int x, int y) {
            System.out.println("methodA");
        }

        public void methodB(int x, int y) {
            System.out.println("methodB");
        }

    }

}
```

This prints

```
methodA
methodB
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing seems to be a more functional programming approach which is not implemented "beautifully" in Java... until now.  I hate to simply link sources, but this is a good overview of what you're trying to do and where Java is at with it.  If you have Java 8 available on this project, you are in luck because it does contain Lambda Expressions (it was just released in March this year).  Here's the link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

You basically want to define functionality and pass it to a method.  Without seeing the source code or project goals, I'm not sure I can comment further.

Comment: I think you are right... so I'm trying to refactor my brain out of functional programming into object oriented programming.  The objects I have include multiple methods.  These methods are in a sense, attributes.  For example: the class plant may have a rate of growing and a rate of flowering.  There may be sub-classes of plants with different growth and flowering rates.  However, I want a plant to show me its growth rate over time, graphically.  The graphical method is generic, but the rate is unique.  So, the input to the graph is a "function" but the method of graphing is generic.